# 413 Request Entity Too Large HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, nginx, highcharts

I am having trouble with the exportation of a certain graph. I have made a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/oy73rgc4/3/) to show with what I am working. This example doesn't contain all the data points with are used, because then my browser (Chrome) crashes. In total i am using about 80K of data points. The HighCharts is displayed like normal and doesn't cause any problems. The problem comes when I want to export the chart!

When I export the chart, doesn't matter if it's PNG/JPG/PDF it always directs to https://export.highcharts.com/ with the message `413 Request Entity Too Large`. I have tried some google'ing

**offline-export.js**

Other people who have experienced this problem had tried to use the JS offline-export. I tried this, but it didn't have any effect.. It just removed the export button in the chart. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4614

**Data grouping**

Some suggested to others to use HighCharts Data grouping. I checked the API but I find that there is too little explanation about this. I think that I can't implement this from scratch and I am unable to find an example http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

**custom exporting server with increased size limit in nginx.conf**

I also found that this option could help. I tried to find instructions, but I don't understand how I need to implement this in my web application (`Laravel 5.2`) http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

Does someone have a new suggestion for me on how I could solve this problem? Or could someone help me out with one of the options which I have suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exporting server is something that you deploy on your server side (i.e. you have to deploy a server to do exporting for you). However, if you only need to export PNG and SVG, then you can do with client-side only solution as per their docs.

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export

If their server seems to have a limit on how big requests it will serve. Means that you have to deploy your own server and configure it (its has to do with actual http server configuration I think) to accept larger requests. Not much you can do on the client, but to limit the amount of data you display on the chart.

P.S. it always directs you to highcharts export server because export functionality by default users their server.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion. The JSFiddle indeed can be exported because it doesn't contain all the datapoints, else the browser crashes (see question)

Comment: In this case, it has to do with limit set on their server. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried your answer but now it just crashes my website. I was already afraid that I have to configure my own server. Don't have any experience with it :-(

Comment: Going with node export server (at least for development) is perhaps the easiest option for now: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server